# ImportError: cannot import name 'TextBlob'

Tags: python-3.x, textblob

I am using textblob for sentiment analysis and find this error. Help me to sort out this error.

`from textblob import TextBlob`

Comment: Have you installed TextBlob?

Comment: Yes I have installed textblob

Comment: Is your program file called textblob.py?

Comment: If your python file is also called textblob.py it will take precedence over the package

Comment: I did everything and change the file name

Comment: Please show the whole stacktrace